# Best way to encrypt a text file in ubuntu (and possibly Android)

Tags: encryption, linux, android, ubuntu

I am currently using a simple 7zip archive that I open with Gnome Archive Manager, and that level of encryption would be fine for my needs, but Gnome Archive Manager does copy the file to the temp directory to allow text editors to access the file, and if I, by mistake, close the Gnome Archive Manager app before the text editor the file remains there.
The same is true if I use 7zip programs in android.

Is there a sort of 7zip program that can open 7zip encrypted archives but also has an integrated, basic, text editor so that a plain version of the file is never exposed outside the program ? (and it would be great if it exists also for Android on top of Linux)

Are there alternative to consider? I am aware of KeePass(xc) but that is a password manager, while I am looking for keep safe just a single text file

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `gpg` or `openssl` to encrypt your a single text file.

```
gpg -cipher-algo <cipher-algorithm> -c /path/to/file
```

List of posiible cipher can be known from `gpg --help`

```
openssl enc <cipher-algorithm> -in /path/to/file -out /path/to/encrypted/file
```

List of possible ciphers can be known via `openssl enc -list`.
No idea about integreted text editor, but you can set the file permission to `000`.

Comment: Password will be asked on command line. Very good idea.

Answer (score 0):

7zip encryption is pretty bad from a security perspective (missing salt, self-made key derivation...), see e.g. this [review](https://dspace.cvut.cz/bitstream/handle/10467/83024/F8-BP-2019-Husek-Josef-thesis.pdf).
I don't know of any program that encrypts files and has an integrated text editor, but there are numerous programs for encrypting individual files: Cryptomator, AES Crypt, File Lock PEA, EncFS...

Comment: For what I understand from that thesis, 7-zip in unsecure if either has been purposely compiled with weak options or the file headers have not been encrypted too in the archive, otherwise it remains quite robust..

Comment: No, it is insecure by design. If you use a long and randomly generated password, it is ok, but otherwise it is easy to crack by using rainbow tables. 7zip works fine for its original purpose, but the encryption scheme is disastrous...